# The string is not callable in Python

Tags: python, pandas, tabulate

I am trying to export a dict to a csv. I am pulling data from an api and need it to print to a CSV.

I am using:

```
import datetime
import csv
import pendulum
import requests
from tabulate import tabulate
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

The API I am calling is below:

```
api_url = "https://secure-webtv-static.canal-plus.com/metadata/cpfra/all/v2.2/globalchannels.json"
response = requests.get(api_url).json()
```

Getting the data I would like to pull is here:

```
tv_programme = {
    channel["name"]: [
        [
            e['title'],
            e['subTitle'],
            pendulum.parse(e['timecodes'][0]['start']
                           ).time().strftime("%H:%M"),
            datetime.timedelta(
                milliseconds=e['timecodes'][0]['duration'],
            ).__str__().rsplit(".")[0],
        ] for e in channel["events"]
    ] for channel in response["channels"]
}
```

I am trying to use Pandas to send the data to the `CSV` file

```
df = pd.DataFrame(tabulate(
    tv_programme["CANAL+ SPORT"],
    headers="firstrow"("Title", "Subtitle", "Time", "Duration"),
    tablefmt="csv",
))
print(tabulate(
    tv_programme["CANAL+ SPORT"],
    headers=["Title", "Subtitle", "Time", "Duration"],
    tablefmt="csv",
))
df = pd.DataFrame(sorted(list(tv_programme.headers('sports.csv'))))
```

The `print` collects the below data and I need this to populate the `CSV` file.

```
Title                                Subtitle     Time    Duration
-----------------------------------  -----------  ------  ----------
Sport Reporter                       Doc Sport    10:42   0:26:23
Chelsea / West Ham                   14e journée  11:11   0:48:38
Cesta punta - Pro Tour 2020          Autre Sport  12:51   1:28:53
Rugby - Golden Lions / Natal Sharks  4e journée   14:20   0:45:56
Rugby - Colomiers / Perpignan        8e journée   15:55   0:50:00
Rugby - Oyonnax / Biarritz           6e journée   17:55   0:50:00
Rugby - Castres / Brive              4e journée   19:55   1:15:00
```

Now this is where I am getting stuck and receiving the error: `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the actual data structure, not the string that's built by `tabulate`.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(tv_programme["CANAL+"], columns=["Title", "Subtitle", "Time", "Duration"])
df.to_csv("canal_plus.csv", index=False)
```

This gives you:

[image]